# flutter The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly

Tags: flutter

I have a question because I have a blockage while running Admob ads.
I'm working on flutter first

I'm doing it while looking at the admob flutter part advertisement addition document.

Currently in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        I have added android:value="YOUR_APP_ID" />
```

and android:value is my app ID in admob.